# SetDataAndType method

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

As documented in [Android Developers page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setDataAndType(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String)) setDataAndType method can be called in this way:

```
auto setDataAndTypeFunctionId = env->GetMethodID(intentClassId, "setDataAndType", "(Landroid/net/Uri;Ljava/lang/String;)V");
jstring jmime = env->NewStringUTF("video/*");
env->CallVoidMethod(context, setDataAndTypeFunctionId, intentObject, UriObject, jmime);
```

But when i run my app this error show on output:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='setDataAndType' signature='(Landroid/net/Uri;Ljava/lang/String;)V' in class Landroid/content/Intent;
```

Comment: You showed only one piece of code in your post. I'd recommend to put two pieces: what is documented as valid call and what actual code you try to run. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the return type, which is not void. The [setDataAndType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setDataAndType(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String)) method returns an object of type `Intent`.

Use the following signature:

```
env->GetMethodID(intentClassId, "setDataAndType", "(Landroid/net/Uri;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;");
```

Also, you should use CallObjectMethod instead of CallVoidMethod, although it doesn't really matter because you're not using the return value.